# How to use LEAST function in Calcite SQL with Apache Beam

Tags: sql, apache-beam, apache-calcite

I'm trying to call the LEAST function in Calcite SQL in my Apache Beam pipeline:

```
...
,LEAST(12.5 + (25 * Quartile), 100) AS PlayedPercentage
...
```

Where `Quartile` is an int32 column. I get the below error:

`Caused by: org.apache.beam.vendor.calcite.v1_20_0.org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorException: No match found for function signature LEAST(<NUMERIC>, <NUMERIC>)`

I've also tried to cast both arguments to Float, but get the same result. How am supposed to call the fuction?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Calcite's SQL Reference](https://calcite.apache.org/docs/reference.html#dialect-specific-operators), `LEAST` is a dialect-specific operator that is only enabled in the Oracle operator table.

If you were connecting to Calcite directly, I would suggest that include `fun=oracle` in the JDBC connect string, and this will enable the Oracle operator table. I'm not sure what the steps are if you are using Calcite from within Beam.